# How to make a videoplayer using FFmpeg on android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I'm trying to make a Video Player using ffmpeg and I use this tutorial http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial08.html, what I understand this tutorial convert a video to a video Image YUV, I'm trying to make the file that interact from .c to .java, I have this

code c from the tutorial08(http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial08.c), then I made

public class RtspReceiver extends Activity {

```
public SurfaceView sfv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.principal);
    sfv=(SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.im);
}

/* load our native library */
static {
    System.loadLibrary("Interface");
}

private static native void Receive(SurfaceView  sf);
```

}

In the c I'm trying to understand how I can use this

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL isec_projecto_rtspreceiver_RtspReceiver_Receive(JNIEnv * env, jobject  obj, jobject Surface)
{
//what I have to put in here?
}
```

How can I put the SurfaceView that I have in the java, in the c???
and other thing, in the tutorial08.c how can I extract the video and put them in the java? am I thinking correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial hasn't been written with Android or Java in mind.

One thing you can do is to do all the `FFMPEG` stuff in your C code, putting your decoded images in a queue. From Java `SurfaceView`, from a separate thread, you will then be passing a bitmap to the native code. In the native code you will be filling the pixels of that bitmap from your decoded images using `AndroidBitmap_lockPixels` and other such stuff.

There is a `'bitmap-plasma'` sample in the NDK. Although it is not related to `FFMPEG` it shows how you can operate on a `Bitmap` from the native code.